# Image link isnt clickable after hover effect has been applied

Tags: html, css

I was following a guide for adding a hover effect to my images to easily display some text on it. The problem is my images also works as links and they are not clickable after the css has been applied. Is there anyway I can make them clickable again?

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.image {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.container:hover .overlay{
    opacity: 1;
}

.text {
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    font-size: 20px;
}

.overlayFade {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #00b1bab3;
}

.container:hover .overlayLeft{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <a href="/carportSpidsTag.jsp"><img src="./IMAGES/fladtTag.png" class="image"></a>
            <div class="overlay overlayFade">
                <div class="text">Fade</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to your `.overlay` rules:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 20px;
}

.overlayFade {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #00b1bab3;
}

.container:hover .overlayLeft {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="/carportSpidsTag.jsp"><img src="./IMAGES/fladtTag.png" class="image"></a>
  <div class="overlay overlayFade">
    <div class="text">Fade</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesomely simple answer. I was about to suggest wrapping the image and overlay inside the anchor element. While that's technically valid in HTML5, this is so much cleaner. Thank you @JesperChristensen!